# Python multithread video processing with Opencv - setMouseCallback not working after stop video

Tags: opencv, events, callback, python-multithreading

I'm trying to process video with OpenCV and Python.

I work with 2 threads, one to read the frames and another to show them.
Now I am trying to stop the video and resume its playback by setting a click callback function with setMouseCallback.

The code works until I stop the video the first time, after that it does not capture the click event again to be able to resume the playback and clicking repeatedly stops working.

Here is my code:

```
import threading, time
import cv2
import queue

capFile = cv2.VideoCapture("../media/videoplayback.mp4")
input_buffer = queue.Queue(4000)

fps = capFile.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
time_frame=1/fps

stopped=False

def clickListener(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global stopped
    if event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        pass
    if event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        print("Stop/Resume video")
        stopped = not stopped

def readFile():
    while True:
        ret, frame = capFile.read()
        if ret:
            input_buffer.put(frame)

def processingFile():
    cv2.namedWindow('Video File')
    cv2.setMouseCallback("Video File", clickListener)
    global stopped
    global frame
    while True:
        if not stopped:
            frame=input_buffer.get()
            cv2.imshow("Video File",frame)
            time.sleep(time_frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            pass
    return

tReadFile = threading.Thread(target=readFile)
tProcessingFile = threading.Thread(target=processingFile)

tReadFile.start()
tProcessingFile.start()
```

Do you have any idea what may be happening?

Comment: When it's stopped, you're not running `cv2.waitKey()`, so the mouse events don't get processed. You always need to run that function to handle all the GUI events, in order to keep the GUI responsive.

Comment: There's a couple of other issues, namely it hangs when you quit early and when you reach the end of the video. Also the timing is not right and the queue size is too large. Other than the timing, here's a [fixed script](https://pastebin.com/YJRNVxYq) -- i'll fix the timing and finish wring the full answer tomorrow.

Comment: @DanMašek Hello, thanks for answering me.

I was reviewing your code, I understand what you tell me about not running `cv2.waitKey ()`

Thank you very much for your corrections, the only thing that I am not finishing to understand is in the final code after `tProcessingFile.join()`

Comment: Oh, looks like vestigial code from before I added timeouts to both of the blocking calls. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem lies in this loop:

```
while True:
    if not stopped:
        frame=input_buffer.get()
        cv2.imshow("Video File",frame)
        time.sleep(time_frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        pass
```

When the video is `stopped` you just enter into an infinite loop that's not doing anything at all. Unfortunately, in order for the GUI to keep working (including processing of mouse events), you need to "pump the message loop" -- in case of the OpenCV HighGUI framework, this means running `cv2.waitKey()` periodically, to handle and dispatch any even handlers, and do things such as redraw the window contents when necessary.

Hence, the first fix would be something along those lines:

```
while True:
    if not stopped:
        frame = input_buffer.get()
        cv2.imshow("Video File", frame)
        time.sleep(time_frame)
    if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == ord('q'):
        break
```

This solves the problem you're asking about. Unfortunately, that's far from enough to get that code working well enough.

---

There are several other issues:

1. Queue size of 4000 is just way too large, and unnecessary (although I suspect why you set it so) -- something like 20 frames should be plenty enough and avoid wasting memory extensively (especially while paused)
2. The timing is not right (it will always run at a lower FPS than it should)
3. Program hangs when you quit (using `q` key) early in a long video
4. Program hangs after it displays whole video

---

**Problem #1** is easy to solve, just reduce the queue size.

**Problem #2** is a little more difficult. The trick here is to synchronize with real time.

First you need to record the starting time -- this is when you expect to display the first frame. You also have to keep track of the number of displayed frames, and this
includes any frames that are repeated while the video is paused.

With this information, you can calculate how long to wait before displaying the next frame, and thus keep a constant (and correct) frame rate.

**NB:** *Key thing to keep in mind here is that all of the operations you perform each iteration take some time. Unless you compensate for that, you will lag behind.*

**Problems #3 a #4** can be resolved by adding a Boolean variable signalling a request to stop, together with adding a timeout to the blocking `Queue` calls. This "stop" signal can be triggered either by pressing `q` key, or by the reader thread reaching the end of the file.

When the reader reaches the end, it will set the "stop" flag to `True`, and end. The processing thread will read the queue until it's empty and at the end it will end as well.

The reader will check the "stop" flag for every frame it reads, as well as whenever it times out while inserting into the `Queue`.

---

Script:

```
import threading, time
import cv2
import queue

capFile = cv2.VideoCapture("f:\\roadtrip\\Roadtrip_01_720p.mp4 ")
input_buffer = queue.Queue(20)

fps = capFile.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
time_frame = 1.0 / fps

paused = False
finished = False

window_name = 'Video File'

def clickListener(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global paused
    if event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        print "%s video" % ("Resume" if paused else "Pause")
        paused = not paused

def readFile():
    global finished

    while not finished:
        ret, frame = capFile.read()
        if not ret:
            finished = True

        while not finished:
            try:
                input_buffer.put(frame, timeout=1)
                break
            except queue.Full:
                pass

def processingFile():
    global finished
    global frame

    cv2.namedWindow(window_name)
    cv2.setMouseCallback(window_name, clickListener)

    start_time = time.time()
    frame_number = 0
    while True:
        if not paused:
            try:
                frame = input_buffer.get(timeout=1)
                cv2.imshow(window_name, frame)
            except queue.Empty:
                if finished:
                    break
        wait_time = (start_time + frame_number * time_frame) - time.time()
        if wait_time > 0:
            time.sleep(wait_time)
        if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == ord('q'):
            finished = True
            print "Playback terminated."
            break
        frame_number += 1
    end_time = time.time()

    print "Video FPS = %0.3f" % fps
    print "Frames rendered = %d (includes repeats during pause)" % frame_number
    print "Time taken = %0.3f seconds" % (end_time - start_time)
    print "Actual FPS = %0.3f" % (frame_number / (end_time - start_time))


tReadFile = threading.Thread(target=readFile)
tProcessingFile = threading.Thread(target=processingFile)

tReadFile.start()
tProcessingFile.start()

tProcessingFile.join()
tReadFile.join()
```

Console output:

*This includes 3 fairly lengthy pauses*

```
Pause video
Resume video
Pause video
Resume video
Pause video
Resume video
Video FPS = 25.000
Frames rendered = 15863 (includes repeats during pause)
Time taken = 635.481 seconds
Actual FPS = 24.962
```